# Using $(this) in jQuery, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, this

Here is my code below...

```
  $('.dp_top_panel_alphabet_ul li').click(function(){

  console.log($(this).attr('title'));

  });
```

This code works fine, my second code is below...

```
 $("[tagname='a']").click(function(){
    $('.dp_right_panel').hide();
    $('.dp_right_show').show();
    var a;
    $('.font_image').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('title').substr(0, 1)=='A'){

        a += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
    }

    });
      $('.fonts_div_show').html(a);

  });
```

This code also works fine but now the problem is that I have to integrate both pieces of code and there is a problem:

```
  $('.dp_top_panel_alphabet_ul li').click(function(){

  var letter = $(this).attr('title');
  var tagme="[tagname="+letter+"]";

     $(tagme).click(function(){
    console.log("[tagname="+letter+"]");
    $('.dp_right_panel').hide();
    $('.dp_right_show').show();
    var a;
    $('.font_image').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('title').substr(0, 1)==letter){

        a += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
    }

    });
      $('.fonts_div_show').html(a);

  });

  });
```

This code is not working... Because of `$this` keyword.

How do I fix this?

Comment: just use a closure as: `var self = this;` then use `a += self.outerHTML;`, if it is your question

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is the same as `this`.

Comment: Hi @all as i have told thats not the problem... second code works fine.. but third code not working....

Comment: Indeed you want then: `if(self.title.substr(0, 1)==letter){`

Comment: great let me try that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $this = this;//Cache your selector here at the top
 ----------------------------------------------------
if ($this.title.substr(0, 1) == letter) {
    a += $this.outerHTML; //now use $this
}
```

Comment: You don't need to make `this` into a jQuery object to get its title attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the element that's been clicked you should use the [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property from the event parameter.